# how to perform a simple join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables, `users` and `players`

In table `users`, I have columns `userid` and `username`.
In table `players`, I have columns `id`, `player1`, and `player2`. Column `id` is an auto increment primary key. Both, `player1` and `player2` are foreign keys of `userid` in table `users`

I'm try to perform a join where I have both `player1` and `player2` usernames in the same row. For example, `userid` 4 has a `username` Sam and `userid` 6 has a `username` Kevin. This would be an example of the query result for just one row:

```
player1  username  player2  username
------------------------------------
   4        Sam       6       Kevin
```

Comment: can u show ur table structures ? coz its confusing... just display here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join a single table multiple times as long as you have unique aliases each time:

```
select p1.userid, p1.username, p2.userid, p2.username
from players p
join users p1 on p.player1 = p1.userid
join users p2 on p.player2 = p2.userid
where ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Player1, u1.UserName, Player2, u2.UserName
FROM Players, Users u1, Users u2
WHERE Player1=u1.userid and
Player2=u2.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

`select a.userid, a.username, b.userid, b.username
from players p
join users a on p.player1 = a.userid
join users b on p.player2 = b.userid
where -------`

Answer (score 0):

try this

> select res1.player1,res1.user_name,res2.player1,res2.user_name  from
>   (SELECT * FROM `test_player` as t1 inner join test_user as t2 on
>   t1.`player1` = t2.user_id ) as res1,(SELECT * FROM `test_player` as t1
>   inner join test_user as t2 on t1.`player2` = t2.user_id ) as res2